# In gitolite, any easier way to create exceptions to users of @all?

Tags: gitolite

For instance, in the repo `PRJ`, there are several groups, like `@A1 @A2 @B1 @B2`, `UserX` is in group `@B1`.

Now I want to add one rule for `UserX`, only allow him to modify the code in `src/` folder, but do not apply this rule to others.
Is there any easier way to implement it?

```
@B1 = UserX UserY UserZ
repo    PRJ
    R               =   @A1 @A2
    RW+             = @B1 @B2
    RW   NAME/      = @A1 @A2 @B2 UserY UserZ
    #RW  NAME/      =   @all-UserX # like this?
    RW   NAME/src/  =   UserX
    -    NAME/      =   UserX
```

Answer (score 0):

Gitolite follows a system of [rule of accumulation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#accum)

> for each user+repo combination, several rules will apply.
>   **Gitolite combines them all into one list (in the sequence they are found in the conf file), before applying the access checks**.
>
> for options and config lines, a later setting overrides earlier ones

There is a way of making deny rules easier to manage with the [**`deny-rules`** directive](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#deny-rules), but it doesn't apply in your case.

This is closer to the rules you see in a [delegation mechanism](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/deleg.html), and would be adapted in something like (not tested)

```
repo Prj
    R                   = @A1 @A2
    RW+                 = @B1 @B2
    RW  VREF/NAME/src   = UserX
    -   VREF/NAME/src   = @all
```