# Gitolite VREF/NAME - what not to push

Tags: regex, perl, git, gitolite

Is it possible to for me to stop members specific group be able to do commit containing ant file other than specified

Example

Stop @legal from pushing commits which contains file other than static/html/legal.html

```
RWC refs/heads/master = @legal
-   VREF/NAME/static/html/[^legal.html]$   =    @legal
```

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in "[In gitolite, any easier way to create exceptions to users of `@all`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16250268/6309)", the access rules follow a [rule of accumulation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rules.html#rule-accum).

In your case, you could grant read-access for all, and deny a directory for `@legal`, except for one file. Something like (not tested):

```
RW  refs/heads/master                 = @all
-   VREF/NAME/static/html             =    @legal
RW  VREF/NAME/static/html/legal.thml  =    @legal
```

The idea is for a more specific rule to [override a more generic one](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/git-config.html#override_conf).

Comment: No, this rejected push to all *.html files; I want be able to get stop in all html files except legal.html

Comment: @forvaidya I thought the more specific rule about `legal.html` would override the one about the `html` folder.

Comment: Solved: I have written my own VREF (akin to MERGE-CHECK) . If my client allows I will post it here

Comment: @forvaidya Sounds great. I will look forward to see that VREF.